# Why is "....although taking..." wrong in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, ing

The Manhattan GMAT Sentence Correction book says that

> Although I take frequent naps, I study effectively

is correct, while

> I study effectively although taking frequent naps

is wrong.

Why is the second sentence wrong ?

Comment: Well, although both examples look like artificial constructs that no-one would really say.

Broadly, they're either both right or both wrong. What's clearly not true is that the first is right and the second wrong.

Comment: The second sentence is not ungrammatical.

Comment: The second sentence is bad because it needs "despite" instead of "although".

Comment: @GregLee Yes, it's a meaning problem, not a grammar problem.

Comment: Here the GMAT enforces what seems to be a grammar **best practice** rather than a **rule**. This is not shocking, as long as it is made clear.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I disagree very strongly with that. Apart from the fact that the statement itself assumes that taking frequent naps somehow interferes with the ability to study efficiently and that it uses _effectively_ where _efficiently_ would be more appropriate, the first sentence is perfectly normal and natural to me. The second sentence, on the other hand, is completely ungrammatical to me. Utterly impossible. In order to function this way, the _although_ clause must precede the finite verb to be grammatical to me: “Although taking frequent naps, I study efficiently” is grammatical.

Comment: @Clare I'm curious which dialect you speak that the second sentence would be considered grammatical in.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What about this? _I study effectively **though** taking frequent naps._

Comment: @JK2 That seems merely awkward to me, but not quite ungrammatical.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you. Do you know, by any chance, of an authoritative source that says that _although_ cannot take a reduced clause (such as _taking frequent naps_) as its complement when it comes after the main clause?

Comment: @JK2 Nope, not off the top of my head. _CGEL_ quite likely mention it somewhere (‘cause they mention pretty much everything), but I don’t know for sure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks. FYI, I bet even CGEL doesn't mention it. All it does mention is that _although_ can take a reduced clause as its complement.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more of the context. My understanding of the GMAT Sentence Correction questions is that there is a prompt consisting generally of one sentence with an underlined extract. This extract may or may not be correct. There are then five possible answers. The first one is identical to the underlined extract and is followed by four alternatives. The testee must choose the best answer - which is not necessarily the only grammatical answer. Is that the case here?

Answer (score 6):

Rachel, a senior member at [thegrammarexchange](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/966107134),
 says:

> While it is possible to construct sentences in this way [although +
>   verb-orientated *ing*-form], they often seem heavy, and are, indeed,
>   an older style. There are some, though few, in the New York Times
>   archives, a lot of them appearing in the years around 1900! Among the
>   following examples, a few are more current....
>
> • Mr. Draskovic, although speaking for many ordinary Serbs, especially
>   here in the capital, is not ''inside the system.'' He said he joined
>   the Government in ...
>
> • although living in a large villa she had been leading a life of
>   comparative poverty, rarely receiving visits apart from a few intimate
>   friends who, ...
>
> • Let's accept that explanation for the sake of argument (although,
>   knowing fans as I do, Clemens might very well have received an
>   ovation). ...
>
> • although, having said that, I think I'm in denial that I am doing it
>   now. Regardless, I think it's a matter of a person's physical
>   condition ...
>
> • The trial must proceed slowly, because the Duke, although having
>   lived in the United States for sixteen years, cannot understand the
>   English language. ...
>
> • although having had many narrow escapes, he was never seriously
>   wounded up to this period. He passed through the eight days' battles
>   in the Wilderness in ...

The examples not containing parentheticals after the 'although' can be seen as deletions, eg

*Mr. Draskovic, although he is/was speaking for many ordinary Serbs, especially here in the capital, is not ''inside the system.'' He said he joined the Government in ...*

(Those with parentheticals after the 'although' are not the same structure.)

Note that the noun-orientated *ing*-form is often used after 'although':

*Although taking a bath immediately after eating is usually not too serious, it is unwise.*

Although the taking of a bath immediately after eating is usually not too serious, it is unwise.

.........

Shoe points out that 'Rachel' (quoted above) later says that she finds

> Although throwing the ball as high as he always does, he doesn’t get
>   much admiration from the girls.

particularly awkward.

Shoe (in a comment) then suggests that "the 'although + present particle' construction works for stative verbs or durative verbs, but not punctual/punctive verbs". This last example is iterative, just to complicate the analysis. I'd say that the present participle isn't the usual choice for a one-off punctive occurrence whether or not 'although' precedes it. But I can find nothing wrong with

> Will Scarlet, although hitting the target, was disqualified for using
>   the wrong colour of arrow.

And addressing Araucaria's point, I'm not sure if one should consider the two events in this example as having the same time-frame or not. I'd agree that some examples sound less acceptable than others, but I think this gets rather complex.

Comment: Ok, I think that deserves a +1. I'd just point out that in your last example (unlike in the others) your (noun-oriented) *ing*-form' is being used because it is the head of a clause used as the subject of the finite form of *BE* (in other words the fact that it occurs after *although* is co-incidental). In the other examples, the *-ing* form is there because the subject has been deleted (because it is interpretable as being identical as the subject of the main clause). Because there is no subject, there can be no tensed verb and therefore the participle form of the verb is used.

Comment: I think the key is elsewhere in the useful page you link to. It seems that the '*although + present particle*' construction works for stative verbs or durative verbs, but not punctual verbs. That is why "*although taking frequent naps*" sounds questionable, whereas in a sentence such as *"Please don't tell me that we have no fuel left" Howard asked although knowing the answer* (https://www.wattpad.com/39813230-monsters-are-real-take-that-fic) the construction sounds acceptable (to me at least).

Comment: @Shoe Fancy doing an answer? Nudge, nudge ...

Comment: @Araucaria. Edwin should get the credit here, for tracking down the useful link. Maybe he could append a paragraph to his answer. BTW, I agree with your first comment above. In fact, the last three of Rachel's examples contain perfect participles, and hence are not necessarily relevant to the OP's question. PS: Do you know what Rachel means when she describes such constructions as '*heavy*'?

Comment: @Shoe No, I don't really know what she's angling at. However, I think there's something else going on here too. Part of that discussion mentions ..."***Note that the present participle, with the –ing form, expresses the same time as the main verb. In your sentences***"  Notice that "I'm studying effectively, although taking frequent naps" sounds perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think a misplaced modifier (ref:[MGSC](http://www.manhattanreview.co.uk/download/MR-GMAT-Sentence-Correction-Guide.pdf), page 65):

> Modifiers are phrases that modify another part of the sentence. In order to be correct, the modifying phrase must be as close as possible to what it modifies.

with 'frequent naps` modifying the student's study pattern. Which makes the first sentence correct over the second.

Also I don't think the second sentence is complete - we could easily extend it:

> I study effectively although taking frequent naps does slow me down
>
> I study effectively although taking frequent naps is often frowned upon by others.

to mean different things. And page 62 states:

> Some answers to GMAT questions are grammatically correct but change
> the meaning of the sentence. Such answers are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The second sentence needs "despite" or at least that is what I was taught. They are both used to show contrast and have the same meaning. The only difference is the way they are used;

> After "although" you need a "subject + verb".

Although it rained a lot, we kept playing.

> After "despite" you need a "noun, a pronoun or -ing".

Despite rain, we kept playing.

I am not really sure but this might be the case because **"despite" is a noun** whereas **"though" is an adverb** (I take "although" and "though" are %100 same though they are not).

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is that You should say...

```
  I study effectively although **I take** frequent naps.
```

I have a few other possible answers.

1. There should be a comma after effectively
   I study effectively, although taking frequent naps
2. In the correct version the structure consists of:

   I take, I study

   In the incorrect version the structure consists of:

   ```
     I study, Taking
   ```

For the "both true or both untrue" idea to work both sentences would need to have the same sentence structure to be reversible.

This may also be a possible solution.

I study effectively, although taking frequent naps.

( I'm not sure if this is correct unless the sentence continues after "naps" to define the reason for the naps ). For example:

```
  I study effectively, although taking frequent naps to rest.
```

My last possible answer...

I study effectively. Although, taking frequent naps.

"I study effectively." can stand on it's own, hence the comma could become a period. The statement is Followed by an expansion on a possible reason for the sentence to be deemed untrue. ( hinting that there may be a more "effective" way to study since they could possibly study better if no naps were taken.)showing contrast to what they said and what they or others may think. 
@Araucaria

Answer (score 0):

The sentence " I study effectively although taking frequent naps." is wrong because, the word "taking" does not specify who or what is taking or being taken  so cannot be separated with a comma or an incomplete sentence would be formed.

To fix this two things must be changed. first the word "taking" should be changed to "I take" and then a comma will need to be added to separate the newly formed sentences from each other.

The correct way to write the sentence would be "I study effectively, although I take frequent naps." @sumelic @raffamaiden